# Using Photoshop to slice a raster image of text questions into individual images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Does anybody know of a place I could look into information about a script that could slice a flat, rasterized image into individual images for each block of text? I have hundreds of pages.

I am working on a single columns where there is a complete row of horizontal whitespace between each question. My ideas were to find the rows of whitespace or to find the pattern of the number before the question. (like (1), (2),...(50), etc) and translate off of that.  Attaching example image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one script that I know of: [Split to Layers](https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/split-to-layers/).

To make it work with this script, there 3 major steps to the process:

1. **Remove the background**

   - This "Split to Layers" script requires the background to be transparent, so you need to remove the background first.
   - I was relatively careful with the background removal, but the script only sees transparency as empty space, not white or any solid color. So if that isn't a factor for you, you can sort of ballpark the background removal without risking deleting any pixels from the text.
2. **Run the "Split to Layers" script.**
3. **Export layers to files** `File > Export layers to files...`

   - If you have an older version, you may find it in: `File > Scripts > Export layers to files...` (or was it `File > Automation > ...`).

**Left** side is the script preview showing how it's about to split it. **Right** side is a gif sort of showing how each layer ended up split.

[image]

You can also copy the script here (Save as "Split to Layers.jsx"):

```
//  photoshopscripts.wordpress.com

////////////////////////////////////
//       Split to Layers 1.0      //
//       2012, David Jensen       //
//                                //
//         With help from         //
//   pfaffenbichler and xbytor    //
//        at ps-scripts.com       //
////////////////////////////////////

#target photoshop

//Change any of the following 5 values to customize the default options for the script:

var showOptionsDialog = true; //Set to false to disable prompt to user.
var tolerance = 0;            // the largest gap of transparent pixels that will be ignored. Also sets default
var confirmThreshold = 20;    // If the script is going to make a large number of layers, prompt user to confirm that this is OK
var suffix = " - ";           // Add this to the Layer name of new Layers.  Set to "" for no additions.
var addCount = true;          // Add a numeral to the end of each new Layer


///////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////
var layerNamePreview=activeDocument.activeLayer.name + suffix;
if (addCount === true){
    layerNamePreview += "1";
}

var originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.POINTS;

bounds = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds
var emptyLayer=false;
if (Number(bounds[0]) == 0 && Number(bounds[1]) == 0 && Number(bounds[2]) == 0 && Number(bounds[3]) == 0) {emptyLayer = true};

try{
    if (activeDocument.activeLayer.kind != undefined && activeDocument.activeLayer.isBackgroundLayer == false && emptyLayer == false){
        activeDocument.suspendHistory("Separate", "main()");
    }else{
        alert( "A supported layer kind is not selected.");
    }
}catch(err){
    alert(err)
}

app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;

function main() {

    var ok=createDialog();
    if (ok===2){
        activeDocument.selection.deselect()
        return false;
    }
    baseLayer=activeDocument.activeLayer;
    activeDocument.quickMaskMode = false;
    activeDocument.selection.deselect()
    var layerName = activeDocument.activeLayer.name
    //if a selection can't be made, stop running the script


    var idCpTL = charIDToTypeID("CpTL");
    executeAction(idCpTL, undefined, DialogModes.NO);

    activeDocument.activeLayer.rasterize(RasterizeType.ENTIRELAYER)
    try{
        var idDlt = charIDToTypeID( "Dlt " );
        var desc120 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref112 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idMsk = charIDToTypeID( "Msk " );
        ref112.putEnumerated( idChnl, idChnl, idMsk );
        desc120.putReference( idnull, ref112 );
        var idAply = charIDToTypeID( "Aply" );
        desc120.putBoolean( idAply, true );
        executeAction( idDlt, desc120, DialogModes.NO );
    }catch(e){}



    activeDocument.activeLayer.name = layerName

    baseLayer=activeDocument.activeLayer



    makeSelection()

    var idMk = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
    var desc642 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNw = charIDToTypeID("Nw  ");
    var idDcmn = charIDToTypeID("Dcmn");
    desc642.putClass(idNw, idDcmn);
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID("Usng");
    var ref535 = new ActionReference();
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
    ref535.putEnumerated(idChnl, idOrdn, idTrgt);
    desc642.putReference(idUsng, ref535);
    executeAction(idMk, desc642, DialogModes.NO);

    newDoc = activeDocument
    // =======================================================
    activeDocument.resizeImage("200%", "200%", undefined, ResampleMethod.NEARESTNEIGHBOR)

    // =======================================================
    var idsetd = charIDToTypeID("setd");
    var desc934 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref535 = new ActionReference();
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
    ref535.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
    desc934.putReference(idnull, ref535);
    var idT = charIDToTypeID("T   ");
    var ref536 = new ActionReference();
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
    ref536.putEnumerated(idChnl, idOrdn, idTrgt);
    desc934.putReference(idT, ref536);
    executeAction(idsetd, desc934, DialogModes.NO);


    var idMk = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
    var desc403 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref288 = new ActionReference();
    var idPath = charIDToTypeID("Path");
    ref288.putClass(idPath);
    desc403.putReference(idnull, ref288);
    var idFrom = charIDToTypeID("From");
    var ref289 = new ActionReference();
    var idcsel = charIDToTypeID("csel");
    var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
    var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
    ref289.putProperty(idcsel, idfsel);
    desc403.putReference(idFrom, ref289);
    var idTlrn = charIDToTypeID("Tlrn");
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
    desc403.putUnitDouble(idTlrn, idPxl, 0.500000);
    executeAction(idMk, desc403, DialogModes.NO);

    var subPathsLength = activeDocument.pathItems[0].subPathItems.length

    if (subPathsLength>confirmThreshold){
        var answer = confirm("Up to "+subPathsLength+ " layers will be created. Would you like to continue?",true)
        if (answer === false){
            newDoc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
            activeDocument.quickMaskMode = false;
            activeDocument.selection.deselect();
            return 0;
        }

    }

    // =======================================================
    activeDocument.resizeImage("50%", "50%", undefined, ResampleMethod.NEARESTNEIGHBOR)

    var pathInfo = collectPathInfoFromDesc(activeDocument, activeDocument.pathItems[activeDocument.pathItems.length - 1])

    // =======================================================
    newDoc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES)

    // =======================================================
    activeDocument.quickMaskMode = false

    // =======================================================
    //make channel
    // =======================================================
    var idMk = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
    var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNw = charIDToTypeID("Nw  ");
    var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNm = charIDToTypeID("Nm  ");
    desc7.putString(idNm, "ContiguityMask");
    var idClrI = charIDToTypeID("ClrI");
    var idMskI = charIDToTypeID("MskI");
    var idMskA = charIDToTypeID("MskA");
    desc7.putEnumerated(idClrI, idMskI, idMskA);
    var idClr = charIDToTypeID("Clr ");
    var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idRd = charIDToTypeID("Rd  ");
    desc8.putDouble(idRd, 255.000000);
    var idGrn = charIDToTypeID("Grn ");
    desc8.putDouble(idGrn, 0.000000);
    var idBl = charIDToTypeID("Bl  ");
    desc8.putDouble(idBl, 0.000000);
    var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID("RGBC");
    desc7.putObject(idClr, idRGBC, desc8);
    var idOpct = charIDToTypeID("Opct");
    desc7.putInteger(idOpct, 50);
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    desc6.putObject(idNw, idChnl, desc7);
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID("Usng");
    var ref5 = new ActionReference();
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
    ref5.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
    desc6.putReference(idUsng, ref5);
    executeAction(idMk, desc6, DialogModes.NO);


    var layerCount = 1
    for (i = 0; i < subPathsLength; i++) {
        //deselect
        var idsetd = charIDToTypeID("setd");
        var desc279 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
        var ref137 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
        ref137.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
        desc279.putReference(idnull, ref137);
        var idT = charIDToTypeID("T   ");
        var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
        var idNone = charIDToTypeID("None");
        desc279.putEnumerated(idT, idOrdn, idNone);
        executeAction(idsetd, desc279, DialogModes.NO);
        ///select alpha channel
        var idslct = charIDToTypeID("slct");
        var desc315 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
        var ref175 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        ref175.putName(idChnl, "ContiguityMask");
        desc315.putReference(idnull, ref175);
        executeAction(idslct, desc315, DialogModes.NO);
        //use magic wand
        var idsetd = charIDToTypeID("setd");
        var desc263 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
        var ref123 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
        ref123.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
        desc263.putReference(idnull, ref123);
        var idT = charIDToTypeID("T   ");
        var desc264 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID("Hrzn");
        var idRlt = charIDToTypeID("#Rlt");
        desc264.putUnitDouble(idHrzn, idRlt, pathInfo[i][0][0]);
        var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID("Vrtc");
        var idRlt = charIDToTypeID("#Rlt");

        desc264.putUnitDouble(idVrtc, idRlt, pathInfo[i][0][1]);
        var idPnt = charIDToTypeID("Pnt ");
        desc263.putObject(idT, idPnt, desc264);
        var idTlrn = charIDToTypeID("Tlrn");
        desc263.putInteger(idTlrn, 1);
        executeAction(idsetd, desc263, DialogModes.NO);

        var idslct = charIDToTypeID("slct");
        var desc346 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
        var ref205 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idRGB = charIDToTypeID("RGB ");
        ref205.putEnumerated(idChnl, idChnl, idRGB);
        desc346.putReference(idnull, ref205);
        var idMkVs = charIDToTypeID("MkVs");
        desc346.putBoolean(idMkVs, false);
        executeAction(idslct, desc346, DialogModes.NO);




        try {
            // =======================================================
            var idCpTL = charIDToTypeID("CpTL");
            executeAction(idCpTL, undefined, DialogModes.NO);

            try {
                var idrasterizeLayer = stringIDToTypeID("rasterizeLayer");
                var desc924 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
                var ref721 = new ActionReference();
                var idLyr = charIDToTypeID("Lyr ");
                var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
                var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
                ref721.putEnumerated(idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt);
                desc924.putReference(idnull, ref721);
                var idWhat = charIDToTypeID("What");
                var idrasterizeItem = stringIDToTypeID("rasterizeItem");
                var idvectorMask = stringIDToTypeID("vectorMask");
                desc924.putEnumerated(idWhat, idrasterizeItem, idvectorMask);
                executeAction(idrasterizeLayer, desc924, DialogModes.NO);
            } catch (err) {}

            try {
                var idIntr = charIDToTypeID("Intr");
                var desc864 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
                var ref658 = new ActionReference();
                var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
                var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
                var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
                ref658.putEnumerated(idChnl, idOrdn, idTrgt);
                desc864.putReference(idnull, ref658);
                var idWith = charIDToTypeID("With");
                var ref659 = new ActionReference();
                var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
                var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
                ref659.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
                desc864.putReference(idWith, ref659);
                executeAction(idIntr, desc864, DialogModes.NO);

                // =======================================================
                var idDlt = charIDToTypeID("Dlt ");
                var desc865 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
                var ref660 = new ActionReference();
                var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
                var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
                var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
                ref660.putEnumerated(idChnl, idOrdn, idTrgt);
                desc865.putReference(idnull, ref660);
                executeAction(idDlt, desc865, DialogModes.NO);

                // =======================================================
                var idMk = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
                var desc866 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var idNw = charIDToTypeID("Nw  ");
                var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
                desc866.putClass(idNw, idChnl);
                var idAt = charIDToTypeID("At  ");
                var ref661 = new ActionReference();
                var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
                var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
                var idMsk = charIDToTypeID("Msk ");
                ref661.putEnumerated(idChnl, idChnl, idMsk);
                desc866.putReference(idAt, ref661);
                var idUsng = charIDToTypeID("Usng");
                var idUsrM = charIDToTypeID("UsrM");
                var idRvlS = charIDToTypeID("RvlS");
                desc866.putEnumerated(idUsng, idUsrM, idRvlS);
                executeAction(idMk, desc866, DialogModes.NO);

            } catch (err) {}

            var finalSuffix=suffix;
            if (addCount===true)finalSuffix += layerCount;


            activeDocument.activeLayer.name = layerName + finalSuffix;
            layerCount++;


            activeDocument.activeLayer=baseLayer;
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    var idsetd = charIDToTypeID("setd");
    var desc1045 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref578 = new ActionReference();
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
    ref578.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
    desc1045.putReference(idnull, ref578);
    var idT = charIDToTypeID("T   ");
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
    var idNone = charIDToTypeID("None");
    desc1045.putEnumerated(idT, idOrdn, idNone);
    executeAction(idsetd, desc1045, DialogModes.NO);

    // =======================================================
    var idDlt = charIDToTypeID("Dlt ");
    var desc694 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref323 = new ActionReference();
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    ref323.putName(idChnl, "ContiguityMask");
    desc694.putReference(idnull, ref323);
    executeAction(idDlt, desc694, DialogModes.NO);


    activeDocument.activeLayer.remove();



    var idHd = charIDToTypeID("Hd  ");
    var desc736 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var list22 = new ActionList();
    var ref541 = new ActionReference();
    var idLyr = charIDToTypeID("Lyr ");
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
    ref541.putEnumerated(idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt);
    list22.putReference(ref541);
    desc736.putList(idnull, list22);
    executeAction(idHd, desc736, DialogModes.NO);

}

//   pfaffenbichler and xbytor    //
//        at ps-scripts.com       //
//      created this function     //
function collectPathInfoFromDesc(myDocument, thePath) {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;

    // based of functions from xbytor’s stdlib;
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    for (var l = 0; l < myDocument.pathItems.length; l++) {
        var thisPath = myDocument.pathItems[l];
        if (thisPath == thePath && thisPath.name == "Work Path") {
            ref.putProperty(cTID("Path"), cTID("WrPt"));
        };
        if (thisPath == thePath && thisPath.name != "Work Path" && thisPath.kind != PathKind.VECTORMASK) {
            ref.putIndex(cTID("Path"), l + 1);
        };
        if (thisPath == thePath && thisPath.kind == PathKind.VECTORMASK) {
            var idPath = charIDToTypeID("Path");
            var idPath = charIDToTypeID("Path");
            var idvectorMask = stringIDToTypeID("vectorMask");
            ref.putEnumerated(idPath, idPath, idvectorMask);
        };
    };
    var desc = app.executeActionGet(ref);
    var pname = desc.getString(cTID('PthN'));
    // create new array;
    var theArray = new Array;
    var pathComponents = desc.getObjectValue(cTID("PthC")).getList(sTID('pathComponents'));
    // for subpathitems;
    for (var m = 0; m < pathComponents.count; m++) {
        var listKey = pathComponents.getObjectValue(m).getList(sTID("subpathListKey"));
        // for subpathitem’s count;
        for (var n = 0; n < listKey.count; n++) {
            var points = listKey.getObjectValue(n).getList(sTID('points'));
            // get first point;
            var anchorObj = points.getObjectValue(0).getObjectValue(sTID("anchor"));
            var anchor = [anchorObj.getUnitDoubleValue(sTID('horizontal')), anchorObj.getUnitDoubleValue(sTID('vertical'))];
            var thisPoint = [anchor];
            theArray.push(thisPoint);
        };
    };
    // by xbytor, thanks to him;


    function cTID(s) {
        return cTID[s] || cTID[s] = app.charIDToTypeID(s);
    };

    function sTID(s) {
        return sTID[s] || sTID[s] = app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
    };
    // reset;
    return theArray;
};


function makePreviewSelection(){
    makeSelection()    
    app.refresh()
    activeDocument.quickMaskMode = false;
}

function makeSelection(){
    try{

        var idsetd = charIDToTypeID("setd");
        var desc922 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
        var ref529 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
        ref529.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
        desc922.putReference(idnull, ref529);
        var idT = charIDToTypeID("T   ");
        var ref530 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idTrsp = charIDToTypeID("Trsp");
        ref530.putEnumerated(idChnl, idChnl, idTrsp);
        desc922.putReference(idT, ref530);
        executeAction(idsetd, desc922, DialogModes.NO);

    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }


    try {
        var idIntr = charIDToTypeID("Intr");
        var desc846 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
        var ref639 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idMsk = charIDToTypeID("Msk ");
        ref639.putEnumerated(idChnl, idChnl, idMsk);
        desc846.putReference(idnull, ref639);
        var idWith = charIDToTypeID("With");
        var ref640 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
        ref640.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
        desc846.putReference(idWith, ref640);
        executeAction(idIntr, desc846, DialogModes.NO);


    } catch (err) {}

    try {
        // =======================================================
        var idIntW = charIDToTypeID("IntW");
        var desc787 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
        var ref572 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
        var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
        ref572.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
        desc787.putReference(idnull, ref572);
        var idT = charIDToTypeID("T   ");
        var ref573 = new ActionReference();
        var idPath = charIDToTypeID("Path");
        var idPath = charIDToTypeID("Path");
        var idvectorMask = stringIDToTypeID("vectorMask");
        ref573.putEnumerated(idPath, idPath, idvectorMask);
        var idLyr = charIDToTypeID("Lyr ");
        var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
        var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
        ref573.putEnumerated(idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt);
        desc787.putReference(idT, ref573);
        var idVrsn = charIDToTypeID("Vrsn");
        desc787.putInteger(idVrsn, 1);
        var idvectorMaskParams = stringIDToTypeID("vectorMaskParams");
        desc787.putBoolean(idvectorMaskParams, true);
        executeAction(idIntW, desc787, DialogModes.NO);
    } catch (err) {}



    if (tolerance >= 2) {

        activeDocument.selection.expand(Math.floor(tolerance / 2))

    }


    activeDocument.quickMaskMode = true;


    var idThrs = charIDToTypeID("Thrs");
    var desc479 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idLvl = charIDToTypeID("Lvl ");
    desc479.putInteger(idLvl, 1);
    executeAction(idThrs, desc479, DialogModes.NO);



    if (tolerance % 2 == 1) {

        var idMtnB = charIDToTypeID("MtnB");
        var desc213 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idAngl = charIDToTypeID("Angl");
        desc213.putInteger(idAngl, 0);
        var idDstn = charIDToTypeID("Dstn");
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
        desc213.putUnitDouble(idDstn, idPxl, 1.000000);
        executeAction(idMtnB, desc213, DialogModes.NO);

        // =======================================================
        var idMtnB = charIDToTypeID("MtnB");
        var desc214 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idAngl = charIDToTypeID("Angl");
        desc214.putInteger(idAngl, 90);
        var idDstn = charIDToTypeID("Dstn");
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
        desc214.putUnitDouble(idDstn, idPxl, 1.000000);
        executeAction(idMtnB, desc214, DialogModes.NO);


        // =======================================================
        var idThrs = charIDToTypeID("Thrs");
        var desc215 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idLvl = charIDToTypeID("Lvl ");
        desc215.putInteger(idLvl, 1);
        executeAction(idThrs, desc215, DialogModes.NO);
    }
}   

function createDialog(){

    var dlg = new Window('dialog', 'Layer Splitter');
    dlg.alignChildren ='left';

    dlg.gap = dlg.add('group')
    dlg.gap.orientation= 'row';
    dlg.gap.txt=dlg.gap.add('statictext', undefined,'Split when gap is larger than');
    dlg.gap.input=dlg.gap.add('edittext', undefined,tolerance);
        dlg.gap.input.preferredSize = [20,20];
    dlg.gap.txt2=dlg.gap.add('statictext', undefined,'pixels');
    dlg.gap.btnPreview= dlg.gap.add('button', undefined,'Preview');
        dlg.gap.btnPreview.preferredSize = [55,20]

    dlg.naming = dlg.add('panel',undefined,'Layer Naming') 
    dlg.naming.alignChildren ='left';
        dlg.naming.suffix = dlg.naming.add('group')
        dlg.naming.suffix.orientation= 'row';
        dlg.naming.suffix.txt=dlg.naming.suffix.add('statictext', undefined,'Suffix:');
        dlg.naming.suffix.input=dlg.naming.suffix.add('edittext', undefined,suffix);
            dlg.naming.suffix.input.preferredSize = [60,20];

        dlg.naming.suffix.chkbox = dlg.naming.suffix.add('checkbox', undefined, 'Add Numeral')
            dlg.naming.suffix.chkbox.value=addCount;

        dlg.naming.txtPreview = dlg.naming.add('statictext', undefined, layerNamePreview)
            dlg.naming.txtPreview.preferredSize = [200,20];

    dlg.btnPnl= dlg.add('group');
    dlg.btnPnl.alignment ='right';
    dlg.btnPnl.okBtn = dlg.btnPnl.add('button', undefined, 'OK', {name:'ok'});
        dlg.btnPnl.okBtn.active=true;
    dlg.btnPnl.cancelBtn = dlg.btnPnl.add('button', undefined, 'Cancel', {name:'cancel'});

    dlg.naming.suffix.input.onChanging= function(){
        layerNamePreview=activeDocument.activeLayer.name + dlg.naming.suffix.input.text
        if (dlg.naming.suffix.chkbox.value === true){
            layerNamePreview += "1"
        }
        dlg.naming.txtPreview.text =layerNamePreview
    }
    dlg.naming.suffix.chkbox.onClick = function(){
        layerNamePreview=activeDocument.activeLayer.name + dlg.naming.suffix.input.text
        if (dlg.naming.suffix.chkbox.value === true){
            layerNamePreview += "1"
        }
        dlg.naming.txtPreview.text = layerNamePreview;
    }




    dlg.gap.input.onChanging = function() {
        if (parseInt(dlg.gap.input.text) == 1){
            dlg.gap.txt2.text = 'pixel'
        }else{
            dlg.gap.txt2.text = 'pixels'
        }
        tolerance = parseInt (dlg.gap.input.text)
    }

    dlg.gap.btnPreview.onClick = function() {
        makePreviewSelection()   
    }

    x=dlg.show(); 

    tolerance = parseInt (dlg.gap.input.text)
    suffix = dlg.naming.suffix.input.text
    addCount=dlg.naming.suffix.chkbox.value

    return x;
}
```

Comment: My files are actually transparent to begin with so I'm excited to give this a try tonight!

Comment: This is really good. I think I can tweak this to have separate threshholds for x-axis gaps and y-axis gaps and then create something that saves each layer as a new image based off the filename of the parent image and then this will be perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @turkeyhundt, I wonder... I've looked inside this script before, though just by skimming... My understanding is that this script makes a selection of the layer and then expands that selection per your demands. There is a section, where it makes that selection into a channel, uses magic wand to select each block and then splits them into their own layers that way. The tricky thing, I think, might be that the step where it makes a selection and expands it, is where the split is sort of decided and I'm not sure how you could separately control the X and Y in that step...

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of a script that would do what you ask for.

I would paste the textimages into Microsoft OneNote and "copy text from image".

Paste the text in a texteditor and tidy it up, removing unwanted line brakes etc. Thus you can recreate the pages with text instead of images. A lot of manual work but doable.