# Rasterizing each letter into a layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to rasterize a text layer in Photoshop CC where each letter gets its own layer?

Comment: yes via a script it is possible but i'm afraid your question is missing details; provide us full information on how  you want to rasterize and use it so we can make a suitable script or other solutions ; include images will be better

Comment: I haven't tried the scripts on that question Sergey linked, but one way could be to rasterize the text and then split it using: [Split to Layers script](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117093/using-photoshop-to-slice-a-raster-image-of-text-questions-into-individual-images/117198#117198). Obviously a script specifically built for that would likely be more bulletproof. Like if you're using a script font where the characters are linked, you wouldn't be able to use the Split to Layers script since it relies on gaps. You might also miss like the dot for `i`  quite easily.